# To solve $x^2dx^2 +y^2dy^2 -z^2dz^2 + 2xydxdy = 0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved differential equations of the form $Px +Qy+Rz =0$. But I am having difficulty to solve this:
$$x^2dx^2 +y^2dy^2 -z^2dz^2 + 2xydxdy = 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

The differential equation can be written

$$(x\, dx + y\, dy)^2 = z^2\, dz^2,$$

or

$$du^2 = z^2\,dz^2 \quad (u = xy).$$

Then $du = \pm z\, dz$, so $u = \pm \frac{z^2}{2} + C$, where $C$ is a constant. That is,

$$xy \pm \frac{z^2}{2} = C.$$